# DataTable row.add with attr id

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a DataTable

```
var tab2=$('#datatable2').DataTable({
        "searching": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "columnDefs": [
           { className: "kiriya", "targets": [ 4 ] }
         ]
        });
```

and i have function to add row

```
tab2.row.add( [
                 tipe,
                 nama,
                 harga,
                 vol,
                 tot
              ] ).draw( false );
```

How to set an  "id" attribute to this row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`row.add()` return a dataTables API along the inserted row, so you can use API methods to set an `id` directly on the `<tr>` node :

```
var row = table.row.add(['a','b','c','d','e','f']).draw();
row.nodes().to$().attr('id', 'someId');
```

Also remember that dataTables add a unique index to the DOM node called `_DT_RowIndex` :

```
console.log(row.node()._DT_RowIndex)
```

would give you the unique index of the inserted record / row, and you can use that as a base for the id :

```
row.nodes().to$().attr('id', 'tr'+row.node()._DT_RowIndex);
```

see a demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4rqq82yr/**

Comment: Thank @davidkonrad for your simple explanation . Its work.